# are function calls in sqlite memoized?

Tags: database, sqlite

Here's setup:

```
.open ':memory:'

CREATE TABLE foos (x INTEGER);
INSERT INTO foos (x)
VALUES (1), (1), (2), (1), (3), (2);
```

Is this query (let's call this `query1`)

```
SELECT x, count(x)
FROM foos
GROUP BY x
HAVING count(x) > 1;
```

slower than this query (`query2`):

```
SELECT x, count(x) AS xcnt
FROM foos
GROUP BY x
HAVING xcnt > 1;
```

In other words, is `query1`'s `count(x)`'s return value implicitly memoized and reused in the `HAVING` clause, or is it actually called twice?

The output of the above is

```
1|3
2|2
1|3
2|2
```

**EDIT:**

Putting an `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` above both queries outputs:

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE foos
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE foos
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

Comment: what happens when you run them? Explain plan:   https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: @MitchWheat I've made edits to clarify my post and added the information you were asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same query.

Also, you should probably create an index on `x`

Comment: Hm, for the record that wasn't me. I found your answer clear and helpful. I'll upvote your answer to balance out the scales.